# How to create "parameters" inside launch files in ROS?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am a little stuck, so some help be very appreciated very much.
I would like to create a list of parameters/variables in the beginning of my launch file, in such a way, that it will available for the user to change the "contents" of the variables, but the rest of the launch file will not change!

Examples:
Nowadays I have the next line in my launch file:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag1" args="play -l $(find guiPackageParametersToCallback)/BagFiles/2011-12-05-10-55-01.bag" required="true"/>
```

But the name of the recorded bag file can change so I want to do something like that:

```
filename = 2011-12-05-10-55-01.bag
<node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag1" args="play -l $(find guiPackageParametersToCallback)/BagFiles/filename" required="true"/>
```

Or in the next case:

```
 <node name="republish1" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=/bb2/left/image_rect raw out:=leftCameraTopic" required="true" />
```

I would like to something:

```
inputTopic = /bb2/left/image_rect
    <node name="republish1" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=inputTopic raw out:=leftCameraTopic" required="true" />
```

Since I am interested to do it in the limits of the launch file itself, I am not sure that "remap" will solve the case here.

Thanks in advance,
Felix.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12289/how-to-create-%22parameters%22-inside-launch-files-in-ros?/) by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 378 on 2011-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to do that is with the `env` tag. So, your code would look like this:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag1" args="play -l $(find guiPackageParametersToCallback)/BagFiles/$(env BAG)" required="true"/>
```

At the command line, you would then type:

```
export BAG="2011-12-05-10-55-01.bag"; roslaunch your_package your_launchfile.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-09**:
Yes, arg is intended for your use case.

**Comment by [Felix Tr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1179/felix-tr/) on 2011-12-09**:
Hi Dmitri, thank you for your answer, but your way is not useful for many parameters. Anyway I have found a good way to do what I want, and this is using "arg" :)